# Laravel - query nested relationship in with method in model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need advice on how to solve my problem.

I have a Model Program that is related to the Foodmenu model. In a relationship using the with method, I want to make a query for nested relationship exchanges, in which I do not want to return meals to which the client is intolerant. In relationship recipes it works but at foods it tells me that id is ambigous. This is probably because exchanges is mapped to the foods table. Do you know how this could be solved?

I enclose the code below:

Program.php model:

```
public function foodmenus()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Foodmenu::class)
        ->with(['recipes.ingredients.exchanges' => function ($query) {
            $client = auth()->user();
            $clientIntolerants = $client->foodIntolerants->where('pivot.program_id', $this->getKey())->pluck('id')->toArray();
            $query->whereNotIn('foods.id', $clientIntolerants)->first();
        }, 'foods.exchanges' => function ($query) {
            $client = auth()->user();
            $clientIntolerants = $client->foodIntolerants->where('pivot.program_id', $this->getKey())->pluck('id')->toArray();
            $query->whereNotIn('id', $clientIntolerants)->first();
        }])
        ->where('visible', true);
}
```

Food.php model

```
public function exchanges()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class, 'food_exchange', 'exchange_id', 'food_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Recipe.php model

```
public function ingredients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class, 'recipe_ingredient', 'recipe_id', 'ingredient_id')->withTimestamps()->with(['alergens', 'category', 'exchanges', 'intolerantClients'])->withPivot(['count', 'grams', 'no_divide', 'order', 'recipe_ingredient_part_id'])->using(RecipeIngredient::class);
}
```

Foodmenu.php model

```
public function foods()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class, 'foodmenu_food', 'foodmenu_id', 'food_id')->with(['alergens', 'category', 'exchanges'])->withTimestamps()->withPivot(['count', 'part_of_day', 'grams', 'drink', 'sidedish'])->using(FoodmenuFood::class);
}

public function recipes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'foodmenu_recipe', 'foodmenu_id', 'recipe_id')->withTimestamps()->with(['ingredients', 'favoriteClients'])->withPivot(['count', 'part_of_day', 'grams']);
}
```

Or would you be able to write a raw query to the with ('foods.exchanges') method that would serve its purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! When you are selecting ID in Query with relationships, you should define table of what ID you want to select.

For example:
$clientIntolerants = $client->foodIntolerants->where('pivot.program_id', $this->getKey())->pluck('id')->toArray();

->pluck() function should be: ->pluck('tablename.id') NOT ->pluck('id').
Thats why it throws "id is ambigous" error

Comment: Yes, I know it, but when I define table foods, it returns me incorrect results. EDIT: in this row $query->whereNotIn('id', $clientIntolerants)->first() is the error occurs